# How to run limited mongoose validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Trying to write a new database entry, and all of a sudden I am starting to get the following error message when I attempt to save the entry.

```
/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:100
      doc.validate(function (err) {
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What I can't understand is what part of the entry is causing this issue. Due to previous issues with the code, I set t up to step through all parts of the data sent from the front end. And it is all there, this is the schema I am using.

```
var  complexSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _creatorId : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    name: String,
    category: { type:ObjectId, ref: 'Categories'},
    sections : [{
        name: String,
        text: String,
        closureType: Number
    }]
});
```

And the code:

```
var comp = new betComplex();
for (var i in req.body){
    console.log("ID: " + i +" DATA: " + req.body[i])
    comp[i] = [];

}
for (var i in req.body.sections){
    console.log("ID: " + i +" DATA: " + req.body.sections[i])
    comp.sections[i] = req.body.sections[i];
    for ( var b in req.body.sections[i]){
        console.log("MEMBER: " + b + " DATA: " + req.body.sections[i][b])
        comp.sections[i][b] = req.body.sections[i][b];
    }
}
comp.save( function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    return res.send(comp._id);
})
```

The problem is that I can't figure out a simple straight forward way to determine which part of the schema (or incoming data) that is causing this issue.

The data going into it

```
id: 0
name: "This is the main name"
sections: {0: {name: "Name of Section 0", text: "<p>Text for section 0</p>↵", closureType: 0},…}
0: {name: "Name of Section 0", text: "<p>Text for section 0</p>↵", closureType: 0}
closureType: 0
name: "Name of Section 0"
text: "<p>Text for section 0</p>↵"
1: {name: "This is the name of section 1", text: "<p>Section 1&nbsp;text</p>↵", closureType: 0}
closureType: 0
name: "This is the name of section 1"
text: "<p>Section 1&nbsp;text</p>↵"
2: {name: "Section 2 name", text: "<p>Section 2 text&nbsp;</p>↵", closureType: 0}
closureType: 0
name: "Section 2 name"
text: "<p>Section 2 text&nbsp;</p>↵"
```

Comment: Added it in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling about, I manage to figure out what the issue is. 
Never did manage to find a smooth way to test the validation, so ended up reducing the bits being saved step by step, and once I did not save the sections it worked.

The problem is that you can not "create" a object in a record, I.E. in this case the sections, I can not create an empty one and populate it. So the trick is to use push. This is how my solution looks.

```
        for (var i in req.body.sections){
            console.log("ID: " + i +" DATA: " + req.body.sections[i])
            comp.sections.push(req.body.sections[i]);
        }
```

Hope this helps someone:)